# Combining two functions to generate token and read blob file content

Tags: c#, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage, blob

I'm new to c#, as I'm working on developing Azure function to generate SAS token, and reading and modifying .docx blob file.

I have these two functions below to do the 2 tasks. However, I want to integrate them into one function. I've tried to do so, but there's something missing I couldn't understand.

```
[FunctionName("SasTokenFunction")]
public static async Task<IActionResult> Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", Route = null)] HttpRequest req)
{

    string connectionString = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AzureStorage");
    CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(connectionString);
    CloudBlobClient client = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
    CloudBlobContainer container = client.GetContainerReference("formsample");

    SharedAccessBlobPolicy accessPolicy = new SharedAccessBlobPolicy
    {
        SharedAccessExpiryTime = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(30),
        Permissions = SharedAccessBlobPermissions.Write | SharedAccessBlobPermissions.Read
    };

    string sasUriToken = $"{container.Uri}{container.GetSharedAccessSignature(accessPolicy)}";

    // return the SAS Token to the client app
    GetUserDelegationSasBlobwithcontent();
    return (ActionResult)new OkObjectResult(sasUriToken);

}

public static async void GetUserDelegationSasBlobwithcontent()
{

    string storageAccountUriString = $"https://formsample5.blob.core.windows.net";
    var credential = new DefaultAzureCredential();

    BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(new Uri(storageAccountUriString), credential);
    UserDelegationKey userDelegationKey = blobServiceClient.GetUserDelegationKey(DateTimeOffset.UtcNow, DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddDays(1));
    BlobContainerClient blobContainerClient = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient("sample");  //container name
    BlobClient blobClient = blobContainerClient.GetBlobClient("Sample.docx");


    // Get a user delegation key 
    var sasBuilder = new BlobSasBuilder()
    {
        BlobContainerName = blobClient.BlobContainerName,
        BlobName = blobClient.Name,
        Resource = "b", // b for blob, c for container
        StartsOn = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow,
        ExpiresOn = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddHours(4),
    };
    sasBuilder.SetPermissions(BlobSasPermissions.Read | BlobSasPermissions.Write); // read permissions

    string sasToken = sasBuilder.ToSasQueryParameters(userDelegationKey, blobServiceClient.AccountName).ToString();
    Console.WriteLine("SAS-Token {0}", sasToken);

    Uri blobUri = new Uri(blobClient.Uri + "?" + sasToken);
    BlobClient sasBlobClient = new BlobClient(blobUri);
    BlobDownloadInfo download = sasBlobClient.Download();
    var content = download.Content;
    using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(content))
    {
        while (!streamReader.EndOfStream)
        {
            string line = await streamReader.ReadLineAsync();
            Console.WriteLine("\nBlob-contents:{0}", line);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you please add a description to your question what is going wrong and what you tried? Without this, it is difficult to help.

Comment: Please use `async void` only for async event handlers. Everywhere else please use `async Task`

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to `Peter Csala` for the comments.

> To combine the two functions, you need to modify the return type of the GetUserDelegationSasBlobwithcontent() function to return the content of the blob file as a string or byte array. Then you can call this function inside the Run() function and pass the SAS token as a parameter to the GetUserDelegationSasBlobwithcontent() function.

To integrate the two functions into one, you can modify the `GetUserDelegationSasBlobwithcontent` function to return the contents of the blob file.
And you can call this function in the `SasTokenFunction` and return the result to the client app.

```
 string blobContent = await GetUserDelegationSasBlobwithcontent(sasUriToken);
 public static async Task<string> GetUserDelegationSasBlobwithcontent(string sasToken)
 {
 .
 .
 }
```

The below namespaces need to be used in the code.

```
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage;
using Azure.Storage.Blobs;
using Azure.Identity;
using Azure.Storage.Blobs.Models;
using Azure.Storage.Sas;
```

I used the code and able to fetch the token.

```
public static class Function1
    {
        [FunctionName("SasTokenFunction")]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", Route = null)] HttpRequest req)
        {

            string connectionString = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AzureStorage");
            CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(connectionString);
            CloudBlobClient client = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
            CloudBlobContainer container = client.GetContainerReference("samplecontainer");

            SharedAccessBlobPolicy accessPolicy = new SharedAccessBlobPolicy
            {
                SharedAccessExpiryTime = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(30),
                Permissions = SharedAccessBlobPermissions.Write | SharedAccessBlobPermissions.Read
            };

            string sasUriToken = $"{container.Uri}{container.GetSharedAccessSignature(accessPolicy)}";

            string blobContent = await GetUserDelegationSasBlobwithcontent(sasUriToken);


            return (ActionResult)new OkObjectResult(sasUriToken);
        }

        public static async Task<string> GetUserDelegationSasBlobwithcontent(string sasToken)
        {
            string storageAccountUriString = $"https://formsample5.blob.core.windows.net";
            var credential = new DefaultAzureCredential();

            BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(new Uri(storageAccountUriString), credential);
            UserDelegationKey userDelegationKey = blobServiceClient.GetUserDelegationKey(DateTimeOffset.UtcNow, DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddDays(1));
            BlobContainerClient blobContainerClient = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient("sample");  //container name
            BlobClient blobClient = blobContainerClient.GetBlobClient("Sample.docx");

            Uri blobUri = new Uri(blobClient.Uri + "?" + sasToken);
            BlobClient sasBlobClient = new BlobClient(blobUri);
            BlobDownloadInfo download = sasBlobClient.Download();
            var content = download.Content;

            using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(content))
            {
                string blobContent = await streamReader.ReadToEndAsync();
                return blobContent;
            }
        }
    }
```

Token generation

[image]

[image]

Sample code to fetch the SAS token.

```
const string ConnectionString = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=<storage-account>;AccountKey=<account-key>";
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(ConnectionString);
            SharedAccessAccountPolicy policy = new SharedAccessAccountPolicy()
            {
                Permissions = SharedAccessAccountPermissions.Read |
                                  SharedAccessAccountPermissions.Write |
                                  SharedAccessAccountPermissions.List,
                Services = SharedAccessAccountServices.Blob | SharedAccessAccountServices.File,
                ResourceTypes = SharedAccessAccountResourceTypes.Service,
                SharedAccessExpiryTime = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(24),
                Protocols = SharedAccessProtocol.HttpsOnly
            };

            return storageAccount.GetSharedAccessSignature(policy);
```

For further information on this, refer to [MSDoc.](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/storage/common/storage-account-sas-create-dotnet.md)